# How can I setup a specific version of cocoapods on codemagic

Tags: flutter, continuous-integration, codemagic

The version of cocoapods in my [codemagic](https://codemagic.io/start/) workflow is lower than what is used by my Flutter project. How can I setup a specific version of cocoapods for my codemagic workflow?

Thank you
Søren

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you get similar message in build log

```
[!] The version of CocoaPods used to generate the lockfile (1.7.2) is higher than the version of the current executable (1.6.1). Incompatibility issues may arise.
```

then you need to uninstall default CocoaPods version first and then install the correct one. You can do it via next pre-build script.

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e # exit on first failed command
set -x # print all executed commands to the log

gem uninstall cocoapods --all
gem install cocoapods -v 1.7.2

cd $FCI_BUILD_DIR/ios
pod install
```

Comment: I have a similar issue with codemagic and iOS build. I cannot, however, figure out, where and how to apply the above script. Would you be so kind and give me some hints?

Comment: @AngelTodorov go to App Settings > Plus sign after Test and before Build section > Pre-build script  if you use yaml file just add those commands to `scripts` block

Comment: Thanks, @Mikhail Tokarev. And in case I want to compile with XCode 11.1 which cocoapods version should I use?

Comment: I think it depends on what version you use locally and what cocoapods version pods are compatible

Comment: Well, this is a problem, since I have no local iOS build - this is why I need codemagic. The thing is, couple of month ago I have built iOS app with Flutter 1.9.1+hotfix6 and Xcode 11.1. Now, I tried the build a new app version with the very same Futter and XCode and the iOS build failed.

Comment: I see... I'd suggest to check latest successful build to find used cocoapods version information or check on rubygems site what was the stable version on that date https://rubygems.org/gems/cocoapods/versions